# How to get website link for git project in EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I have created a git repository in my own ec2 instance inside var/www/html folder but I am unable to get the project URL or simply the website URL.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify your situation? What do you mean by "project URL" and "website URL"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the project URL I mean the path of git and by website URL I meant the index file inside the git project folder.

Comment: With AWS you need to 'wire' that all up yourself.  It is not the same as traditional hosting where you have an IP address to the instance.  Follow the documentation carefully:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html